# d3.nest with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv with the following structure, and I want to create a multiple lines chart in d3:

```
date,value1,value2,value3
1924-01-01,433.57,16.21,122.09
1925-01-01,247.68,18.55,115.38
```

To do so, I need to obtain the following structure:

```
date,category,n
1924-01-01,value1,433.57
1924-01-01,value2,16.21
1924-01-01,value3,122.09
1925-01-01,value1,247.68
1925-01-01,value2,18.55
1925-01-01,value3,115.38
```

I've tried different approaches, withtout success. For example:

```
d3.csv("data.csv",function(data) {

var values = ['value1','value2','value3']

var nestedData=d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {return d.values;})
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
  .entries(data)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes?! I'm really confused, my problem must be somewhere else. Thank you for your advice! I'll keep searching.

Comment: In particular you don't need to use `d3.nest()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) does exactly the same thing you're looking for, without `d3.nest()`. The data structure there is the same as yours (except it's tab and not comma-separated):

```
date    New York    San Francisco   Austin
20111001    63.4    62.7    72.2
20111002    58.0    59.9    67.7
20111003    53.3    59.1    69.4
```

This is the code that in the example does the data transformation (comments added for explanation):

```
// get the names of all the different series (everything that's not called "date")
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

// parse the dates
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

// restructure the data
var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
  // for each series, create an object with its name and its values
  return {
    name: name,
    // extract the value for the series we're processing at the moment from the data
    values: data.map(function(d) {
      return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
    })
  };
});
```

The only thing you have to change to use this code is the date format. You may want to change the variable names as well to make it clear what you're dealing with.

Comment: Thank you so much! With all your comments, I really understand everything, it's very educative. I appreciate the time you took for it.